# tagging dictionary data

Tags: python

I would like to do something equivalent to "tagging" a dictionary element.

Here is some pseudo-code to illustrate the idea:

```
mydict = dict()
mydict['thiskey'] = 'myvalue'
#then i would like to do this:
mydict['thiskey'].tag = 1
```

is there anything like this?
or maybe i could just append to the value somehow?
but i would need to know how to still access the original value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> class MyStr(str):pass
... 
>>> mydict = dict()
>>> mydict['thiskey'] = MyStr('myvalue')
>>> mydict['thiskey'].tag = 1
```

Comment: And if I were *not* to use tagging- Could I simply use something like mydict['thiskey'] = (myvalue, 1) ?  If so, how would I edit the value of the 2nd item?  Would it be like mydict['thiskey'][1] = 33  or similar?

Comment: @jml, well you couldn't use a tuple, but a list would work - `mydict['thiskey']=[myvalue, 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities I can think of are either creating a simple TaggedData class containing just a tag and value.  Or using a dictionary as the value with only the keys 'tag' and 'value'.

Answer (score 2):

```
mydict = dict()
mydict['thiskey'] = TaggedObject("myvalue")
mytag = Tag("tagName")
mydict['thiskey'].tag = mytag
```

So you need to create two classes `TaggedObject` and `Tag`, but the latter is optional: you can simply use a string and write this:

```
mydict = dict()
mydict['thiskey'] = TaggedObject("myvalue")
mydict['thiskey'].tag = "tagName"
```